# Number of conjugacy classes of $GL_3(\mathbb{F})$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to determine, using rational canonical form, the number of conjugacy classes of $GL_3(\mathbb{F})$, where $\mathbb{F}$ is a finite field.

If I'm not mistaken, then the following three are the only options:

(1)
$$\left[ \begin{matrix} a & 0 & 0 \\0 & a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & a \end{matrix}\right]$$

where $a$ has $|\mathbb{F}|-1$ options (must be non-zero)

(2)
$$\left[ \begin{matrix} a & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & b \\ 0 & 1 & c \end{matrix}\right]$$
[**Not sure about the following analysis, since the second companion matrix should depend on the first)]** where $a$ has $|\mathbb{F}|-1$ options (must be non-zero), $b$ also has $|\mathbb{F}|-1$ options and $c$ has $|\mathbb{F}|$ options (it being zero does not affect the determinant). In total this yields $(|\mathbb{F}|-1)^2|\mathbb{F}|$ options. **[Or, in light of the above comment - it should be $(|\mathbb{F}|-1)^2$ if we observe that $b=ad$ and $c=a+d$ for some $d$
since the minimal polynomial has to be $(x-a)(x-d)$?]**

(3)
$$\left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & a \\1 & 0 & b \\ 0 & 1 & c \end{matrix}\right]$$
where $a$ has $|\mathbb{F}|-1$ options and $b,c$ have $|\mathbb{F}|$ options.
In total this yields $(|\mathbb{F}|-1)|\mathbb{F}|^2$ options.

Altogether we have: $|\mathbb{F}|-1 + (|\mathbb{F}|-1)^2|\mathbb{F}| + (|\mathbb{F}|-1)|\mathbb{F}|^2$ conjugacy classes.

Is this correct?

Comment: The RCF insists that we have $C(d_1)\oplus C(d_2)\oplus \dots$ with $d_1\mid d_2$ as you know. So it's your second option in case (2).